# Energy cost of chewing vs production of enzymes

Tags: enzymes, bioenergetics, digestion

Consider a hypothetical case that you ingest a piece of starch. Which is more costly energetically 1) chewing + reduced amount of enzymes production needed or 2) sole production of all the enzymes for digestion **for achieving the same amount of glucose absorption** given the digestion time is constant. (There could be different answers for different sizes of starch ingested)

Comment: I think an important consideration is the digestion efficiency. Whole food would have to be broken down from the outside-in. By chewing or otherwise mechanically disaggregating the food, the surface area exposure to digest enzymes is increased, which is more beneficial if the endpoint is products liberated over time.